# Using a method will not change my object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, computer-science

I made a method to add seconds to a time. For example, if I had one hour 15 minutes, and I used this function and added 15, the new object should read 1 hour 30 minutes.  However, when I do `currentTime.increment(10)` in one line, then I `print(currentTime)` on the next line, what prints is the old `currentTime`, not updated.

I am new to classes so I do not know if they update like lists do. If I defined a `list = [2,3,4]` and I appended a new entry, it would edit the original list so I could `print(list1)` and it would be the old list with the new entry. Why does that not work here and why does it only work if I do it all in one step, like `print(currentTime.increment(10))` ?

```
class MyTime:
    """ Create some time """

    def __init__(self,hrs = 0,mins = 0,sec = 0):
        """Splits up whole time into only seconds"""
        totalsecs = hrs*3600 + mins*60 + sec
        self.hours = totalsecs // 3600
        leftoversecs = totalsecs % 3600
        self.minutes = leftoversecs // 60
        self.seconds = leftoversecs % 60
    def to_seconds(self):
        # converts to only seconds
        return (self.hours *3600) + (self.minutes *60) + self.seconds
   def increment(self,seconds):
        return MyTime(0,0,self.to_seconds() + seconds)

currentTime = MyTime(2,3,4)
currentTime.increment(10)
print(currentTime) # this gives me the old currentTime even after I increment
print(currentTime.increment(10)) # this gives me the right answer
```

Comment: Why do you throw away the incremented return value of `currentTime.increment(10)`? The `increment()` method creates a new `MyTime` object, it does not modify `self`.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the different between mutating methods (like `append` on a list) and copying methods (like `replace` on a string). You've written a copying method, but you're expecting it to work like a mutating method. Do you not get the difference, or do you not get why your method is not a mutating method?

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def increment(self,seconds):
    return MyTime(0,0,self.to_seconds() + seconds)
```

This makes no attempt to modify the `self` object passed into the function.  You does *refer* to the object, but in a read-only fashion.  You call `to_seconds` to retrieve the "seconds" version of the object; this result goes into a temporary variable.  You then add then `seconds` parameter to that temporary variable.  Finally, you return the sum to the calling program ... which then ignores the returned value.

You need one of two things: either store that result back into `currentTime.seconds` in the main program, or into `self.seconds` within the method.  In the latter case, don't bother to return the value: it's already stored where needed.  I recommend the second case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you meant to do this:

```
def increment(self, seconds):
    self.seconds += seconds
    return self.seconds
```

`self` refers to the instance itself - the one you are currently interacting with.